# formatting json data from a string in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to format the data passed by the api in to key value paris for use with javascript the data right now is one big key and not in key value paris how can i get the data as  key value paris and properly formated ?

```
<?php

     header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $url = file_get_contents('https://www.jiosaavn.com/api.php?_format=json&query=mere%20angne%20mein&__call=autocomplete.get');
    $data = explode('[', $url);
    $format = json_encode($data[1], true);
    print_r($format);

    ?>
```

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: updated the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response contains some HTML which has to be removed to be able to parse the json. This can be achieved with `strip_tags`. After removing the html `json_decode` can be used to get the values:

```php
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://www.jiosaavn.com/api.php?_format=json&query=mere%20angne%20mein&__call=autocomplete.get');

$content = strip_tags($content);
$response = json_decode($content);

print_r($response);

foreach($response->albums->data as $album){
  echo $album->title;
}
```

result:

> Mere Angne MeinLaawarisMere Angne MeinMere Angne Mein (From "Mere Angne Mein")Mere Angane Mein

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://www.jiosaavn.com/api.php_format=json&query=mere%20angne%20mein&__call=autocomplete.get';
    $data = file_get_contents($url);
    $format = json_decode($data);
    print_r($format);
```

Comment: Please add the explanation why this answer is correct